# How can I make jBuilder output as XML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json

I want the XML representation of my models to exactly mirror its JSON representation. I have jBuilder setup using templates and everything is working nicely. I'm under the impression that jBuilder builds up a hash before encoding it to a JSON string, does anyone know how to instead encode it to XML? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

jBuilder has #attributes! method which returns the attributes that are going to be encoded to JSON. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like what I'm looking for. Do you know how I can initialize the jBuilder instance?

Comment: What do you mean? Just do json=Jbuilder.new. And then like usual: http://rdoc.info/github/rails/jbuilder/frames

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, I wound up going with rabl: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl